# PHP: just saying $someVariable; inside a function - does this do anything

Tags: php, variables

I'm working on some PHP code (that I didn't write). Here and there inside functions there's stuff like this:

```
$foo;

if ($someCondition) {
    $foo="some value";
}
return $foo;
```

Just checking: that first $foo; on a line by itself - it has no effect whatsoever, right?

Comment: Nope it does nothing. Maybe a typo?

Comment: maybe the variable is set to a function that return true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is debug code left over from **PHP3 or PHP4**. These versions generated an E_NOTICE for just mentioning a variable (it was implicitly a read access):

```
$undef;   // E_NOTICE
```

PHP5 however does not treat it as variable access anymore. So it goes ignored.

---

PHP3: **Warning**:  Uninitialized variable or array index or property (undef)

PHP4: **Notice**:  Undefined variable:  undef

PHP5: *silence*

Answer (score 0):

Your right. Maybe original developer come from another language and "declare" used vars.

Another way to write this code snippet is

```
if ($someCondition) {
    return "some value";
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have some impact if it were:

```
global $foo;
```

But in the form you posted, it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Right, no need for it at all. Some languages require a variable to be declared, not PHP.

In PHP, you can even concatenate into an undeclared variable. PHP is the loose hipster of the programming world. Anything goes, man.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's lazy instantiation. I'd change the line to `$foo = ""`, which should have the same effect;

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if they think that its the equivalent to defining a variable to prevent errors when strict error reporting is enabled - although it actually doesn't (define the variable) when its written like that